# Cycle between li drawers - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, html-lists, slidingdrawer

I've got a set of li drawers that when you click on each one it expands. But I dont want it to be interact-able I want this to cycle, expanding the next li drawer every 5 seconds for example. Also, the number of li drawers isnt fixed to 3. I want it to still cycle through all even if i add more li drawers to it. Hope that makes sense.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WApV/

I've tried having a go at this myself using setInterval and .next().slideDown() but wasnt getting anwyhere. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bam = $('H2.drawer-handle'),
    count = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
    if (count <= 1) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
    var item = $('H2.drawer-handle').get(count);
    $(item).click();
}, 1500);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7WApV/1/

Comment: Thanks, but if add another li drawer to it, it just ignores that?

Comment: Nice work. But I found a very small mistake in your code. Either you removes 'bam = $('H2.drawer-handle'),' or you use 'var item = $(bam).get(count);'. As I said, just a very small mistake.

Comment: @Khan: change the line 'count <= 1' to 'count <= ($(bam).size() - 1)'